# php return empty array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here the problems:

The line: `echo($arr)` prints `"arrayarrayarray...."` on the screen (I added this line only to see what's inside $arr).

The encode command prints nothing.
But last week was working!!

Please, help! Thanks in advance.

```
$query="select nome, categoria, produttore, descrizione,prezzoquantita,unitaquantita, prezzopezzi, informazioni, foto, flagpezzi, unitamisura from prodotti;";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;
        echo ($arr);
    }
}

print (json_encode($arr, true));
```

Comment: @soul You forgot a `$` ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yup sorry added it

Comment: try `var_dump(json_encode($arr, true));`

Comment: *"But last week was working!!"* - So, what "changed" since? *Ah,*... that...... is the question.

Comment: Echoing `$arr` won't return anything unless you pass the `key` inside it, like `$arr['nome']` or `$arr['categoria']` or `$arr['descrizione']`... But I started to laugh when I read _But last week was working!!_... What have you changed since that?

Comment: I came to think that the code started to change itself during the weekend. One would call that a "Self-modifying code". When your code even starts to become self-conscious, you'd better be really careful...